# Display Custom Text in all page in Magento 1.9 using module

Tags: magento-1.9

I am new to Magento 1.9 and i am trying to create a **module** that going to display some static text in every page.Can you please suggest any idea.

Display Text in **frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog/msrp/popup.phtml
** area .I have attached screenshot of the image as below for the reference.

[image]

Comment: Where you want to display that?
Do you have any screen shot for understanding?

Comment: I have shared the image for the reference . Every page i have an area named **frontend\rwd\default\template\catalog/msrp/popup.phtml** , now i am trying to display some static text into this area , via module only.For Example , **Welcome all** is my text means , then that text will display below the top menu (  women , men and etc..) of all pages.Can you understand what i am coming to say ?